# For loop in sql plus

Tags: sql, batch-file, for-loop

I tried to make a script to connect to hosts 5001 - 5100 by using a loop.

```
connect user/f@s5001s
```

So I thought it would be a good idea to use a variable between `@s____s`, like in a bash script.

```
for /L %%yo in (5001..5100)
connect user/f@s$$yos
```

The problem is, as far as I understand, you can't do that in `sqlplus`. How can I solve this?

Comment: Let me get that straight - you're trying to connect to 100 different Oracle databases?

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop syntax is incorrect; loop variables can only be a single character (although they are case-sensitive, so at least you have 52 instead of 26), and you need `do` at the end of the first line. Additionally, `for /L` requires the syntax `for /L %%variable in (start,step,end) do command [command-parameters]`

```
for /L %%Y in (5001,1,5100) do connect user/f@s%%Ys
```

Comment: There is no "connect" command in a Windows batch file. You would need to use `sqlplus` instead of `connect`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the problem is that sqlplus does not recognize this loop syntax